# How to make a cone with tip inside

Tags: geometry

Its easy to make a cone - cut of a circle out of papet and make a radius cut, then fold it and you have a cone. I noticed that i can push its vertex inside cone with a bit rough force so its would have half of its height. And its tip vertex would be exactly in center of base circle.

So it is physically possible object with a some circular fold, with `radius = radiusOuter/2`

Now i have thick aluminium foil ~300 micrometers, and i need to get that shape out of it. I still can make cone, but i have insuffient force to push its tip inside and make the task carefully. Is there any way to make it without crumpling the foil?

UPD. To phohibit answers, involving random crumpling by attaching infinite force to cone vertex from above: Better we can replace paper/aluminium with steel, to make it almost impossible to do bends and cuts without heavy machine labor. The question is - what algorithm can you offer for machine to manufacture such an object efficiently, with "least effort" or "least wasted energy", without destroying material of the object?

UPD2. welding and any other kind of gluing is denied, to phohibit manufacturing cone and cutting it in half, then reversing tip part and welding it back along the cut line.

Comment: Downvoted for changing the question after answers were submitted. You also negated the original question which requires two radial cuts in the circle so it can be bent to form a cone, because cuts are now not allowed.

Comment: ... and bends are now forbidden too, required to form a cone. The original question was interesting but has become nonsense.

Answer (score 2):

Consider the original cone, and add to it the closing bottom disc. You obtain a closed surface $S$ homeomorphic to a $2$-sphere. In the smooth parts of $S$ the Gaussian curvature is $\equiv0$. Nevertheless $S$ has total curvature $4\pi$, by the Gauss-Bonnet theorem.  A certain part of this total curvature, say the amount $\lambda>0$, is invested in the apex, and the rest $4\pi-\lambda$ is uniformly distributed along the lower circular rim. If you now succeed in pushing the apex down to the center of the base disc you obtain a new closed surface. The total curvature is still $4\pi$, but now we have $\lambda$ at the inward apex, still $4\pi-\lambda$ along the base rim; furthermore a "dipole" of total curvature $\lambda$ and $-\lambda$ has been created along the new rim at height ${h\over2}$. (See the following figure, where the rims have been smoothed out to toroidal pieces of surface.) The question is whether your material will support this singularity without propagating some of the resulting forces into the interior of the surface which then will destroy its microstructure.

[image]

Comment: And now imagine that i can cast an ingot of steel (or aliminium) to that form (if i just have vertical and horisontal press forms). So there would be no inner tension and forces almost at all. And i could retain same thickness in every point. that's an object. So if i have a sufrace of that material of exact such thickness - how could i convert it to this object not using melting/welding/gluing? Or can you proove it is impossible?

Comment: What did you use for your diagram?

Comment: @Neil: I use "Canvas Draw 3, for Mac" for my figures here.

Comment: @ChristianBlatter  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Working with paper, I first tried to make one by cutting several radial slits from the centre to half radius, but this did not work because it is not possible to fold along a curved line, and making a large number of slits to approximate folding along a straight line is a poor solution because you have that many cuts to join: not just one, so impossible (deleted the above comment).

Next, I drew a circle of half radius on the paper, and (having cut out a seqment) worked carefully around the half radius several times, creasing it locally and gently with fingers and thumbs without distorting the paper further away.

Then when I curved the paper into a cone, the inner part naturally formed the inner concave cone you asked for, without any effort. I hope this technique will work for aluminium. But it is approximate, not perfect.

---

A solution could be to use a material that naturally stays flat and recovers from distortion. But that won't form the required crease at half the radius.

So the answer to your question

> Is there any way to make it without crumpling the foil?

is "No."

Comment: so as you said - "fold along a curved line" - is a crucial operation, making it impossible to manufacture a possible physical object in a real world.. what a strange thing - oblect can exist, but you cant do it! okay. what kind of indulgence to the original statement of the problem can we gave, to get result in real world, closer to perfect ? (especially if we have harsh material, which is very hard to randomly "force-crumple" inside?)

Comment: Perhaps a machine could be programmed to follow the half-radius curve time after time, to gently work towards a sharp fold, better than my fingers can. I look forward to at least an upvote for my efforts, even though it isn't - and can't be - the perfect answer.

Comment: But you have now changed the question, and the new answer is to make two parts in steel and weld them together.

Comment: Question is not quite about material, but about non-destroying operations as much as possible, to avoid welding and crumpling it! Or to explain WHY it is impossible It's not physics question, but related to geometry much more.

Answer (score 0):

If there is a requirement for the slant edges to be joined for the cone and the tip, only fix the edges together for the height of the tip you want inside, and pull up and fold the rest of the cone whose slant edges are not fixed. Then join those slant edges.